# Angular 1.x migration performance issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I am upgrading a huge angular 1 project from 1.3.x to 1.6.x because we require some patches in the latest version. After updating it seems that the entire application has slowed dramatically. I have been looking through the migration documentation but is there anything that could be causing major slow downs? Any bad code or gotchas that would cause this? I am having issues just with visual changes such as ng-show and ng-hide being slow and twitchy.

This is the CPU profile before upgrade:
[image: CPU profile before]

This is the CPU profile after upgrade:
[image: CPU profile after]

Thank you!

EDIT:

Let me give a little more context. I have a feeling this has to do with the digest cycle. For example, I a navbar where an icon will hide and another will show on hover.

Here is what it looks like in angular 1.3
[image: 1.3 cpu]

Here is what it looks like in angular 1.6
[image]

I am getting a forced reflow performance warning after the update. Also this (recalculate style) is directed from angular-animate s computeCssStyles function (or at least that is the line of code it's directing me towards). I am also not calling any of $animate in my code. Is this just a product of the angular digest method? Also is there anything that I am missing from the migration docs about possible changes to digest?

Code example:
showDropdown is changed from false to true on hover and visa versa.

```
<i> ng-show="! showDropdown" </i><i> ng-show="showDropdown" </i>
```

EDIT:
Short term fix as I am not using animate anywhere in my code but it seems to be firing as per the newer angular digest method. I just disabled animations as a partial short term fix.

```
$animate.enabled(false);
```

Comment: I know it may take time, but what about using ng-if instead of ng-show/hide ? if you're hiding directives, they will still run, with ng-if they won't be compiled unless necessary - that is less watches during runtime when are hidden. Also, which visual changes you mean ? does your model needs to be evaluated if you just show/hide images ? Maybe you can do some work on it so digest cycle is not fired

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I will give ng-if a try. I will just have to change that across a lot of directives. The visual changes I am talking about are as simple as a navbar. Where we have two different icons that hide and show based on a variable.

`<i> ng-show="! showDropdown" </i><i> ng-show="showDropdown" </i>`
When the showDropdown variable changes it shows both for a split second and then hides the other.

Comment: It is unlikely that the question can be answered. It requires an example that can replicate the problem. The fact that visual parts are involved says literally nothing. They are just updated on digest. Of course, they will expose lags - because they are visual.

Comment: could you please provide us with the plunker or fiddle, so that we could find the root cause. There could be so many reasons which must be degrading your app performance. A simple example would be the unnecessary use of two-way data bindings where you actually need one-time binding. You can install a chrome extension named batarang to actually check the number of digest cycles that are getting fired, and how many watchers are registered in your app.

Comment: @Pramod_Para the batarang extension seems to be just crashing the app when enabled, I will look into it more when I have some extra time. The number of watchers are around 2000... Depending on what page. I don't think I would personally be able to accurately create a fiddle for a performance issue on this scale.

Comment: I recommend [AngularJS Inspect Watchers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-inspect-watcher/gdfcinoagafkodbnkjemaajfahnmfkhg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) - you can check part of page for watchers

Comment: @Alexg2195, there is golden thumb rule to remember, if number of watchers goes beyond 2000, your application performance starts degrading

Comment: @Pramod_Para I do know that as a good rule of thumb, My issue doesn't seem to have an issue with that. I have pages with 4000+ watchers that have no performance issues on angular 1.3 but have many issues on 1.6. My question pertains to what changes may have happened over that time in how updates happen during digest that would cause such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Managing memory is difficult in JavaScript. Here are few best practices to improve the performance in terms of loading pages and freeing memory.

- Removing Detached Node manually - Work on to remove detached object.

```js
var myNode = document.getElementById("bodyPanel");
  if(myNode !== null){
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
  }
}
```

- On every page switch, call destroy inside Angularjs controller. Also javaScript object Reference to `null`

```js
$scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
  $window.off("resize.Viewport");
});
```

- Create Angular js Service to keep important data in memory to avoid fetching from HTML5 storage system.
- As mentioned in comment, use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`.